# Given $A \in O(n,\mathbb{C})$, why must $det(A) = \pm 1$ but for $A \in U(n)$ we have that $det(A) = e^{i\theta}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I understand that for $A \in O(n,\mathbb{R})$ we have that $det(A) = \pm 1$.

---

Now, we have that  $A \in O(n,\mathbb{C})$ if and only if $A$ preserves the bilinear form $\langle x,y \rangle = x_1y_1 + ... + x_ny_n$ (Note that this is not an inner product since it is not conjugate symmetric.) Thus, $A \in O(n,\mathbb{C})$ if and only if $A^{tr}A = I$ and so in this case we have that $det(A^{tr}A) = det(A)^2 = 1$; therefore $det(A) = \pm 1$.

Similarly, we have that  $A \in U(n)$ if and only if $A$ preserves the inner product $\langle x,y \rangle = x_1\bar{y_1} + ... + x_n\bar{y_n}$. Thus, $A \in U(n)$ if and only if $A^*A = I$ and so in this case we have that $det(A^*A) = |det(A)| = 1$; therefore $det(A) = e^{i \theta}$ for some $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$.

Okay... There is something subtle here that I'm not understanding. I really don't understand what exactly is causing an orthogonal matrix with complex entries to always have a real determinant.

Why is it that preserving the bilinear product forces the determinant to be real, whilst as soon as we have conjugate symmetry, and thus an inner product, the determinant can be imaginary?

Comment: Try scalars. In the reals the only numbers with $|x| = 1$ are $\pm 1$ but in the complex numbers is is any $e^{i \theta}$.

Comment: But $O(n,\mathbb{C})$ is made up of matrices with complex entries..?

Comment: And any element satisfies $U^*U = I$ so $|\det U| = 1$.

Comment: @copper.hat you should also mention that $\theta\in{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw This is the comment section, not the legal disclosure part.

Comment: @copper.hat 

Comment: @NobelCat The difference is that in one case you have $U^T U = I$ and the other $U^* U = I$.

Comment: (responding to [second comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4338801/given-a-in-on-mathbbc-why-must-deta-pm-1-but-for-a-in-un-we#comment9049452_4338801)) Okay, so when $n = 1$, can you list all the complex numbers, $z$, such that $z^{\text{tr}}z = z^2 = 1$, then all the complex numbers, $z$, such that $z^*z = |z|^2 = 1$?

Comment: @N Perhaps a helpful reframing of the question is "why is $\det(A^{*}A)$ necessarily real (and positive) while $\det(A^{tr}A)$ can be any complex number?" We can see that $A^*A$ has a real determinant by noting that it is Hermitian and applying the spectral theorem. We can see that its determinant must be positive by noting that $A^*A$ is positive semidefinite.